# How can I store graphics components together in a logical structure?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java-2d

I have written a game of hangman and I would like to add some Java2D graphics too it. I am sure most people know this, but just in case let me make it explicit. In hangman, after each mistake a tiny little bit of a "hanging" stick figure is drawn until its complete.

Therefore, when I draw this the logical way is to run a `for` loop and draw as many components as there are mistakes. Since I know what order I need to draw components in, I can loop through an array type in order for drawing. Now if I was just using `java.awt.Rectangle`s than this would be easy, create an array of `Rectangle`. However, since for hangman I also use one `Ellipse2D`, I need a way to store both graphics components together in an array type format. What could I use to do this? (I have heard of ArrayLists but I don't really know how to use them at all and I believe you need to still specify an object type for these)

Example code would also be greatly apreciated. If this is impossible, let me know also, since I can just draw the head independently.

```
static int mistakes = 3;
static Ellipse2D head = new Ellipse2D.Double(420, 210, 160, 160); 
static Rectangle torso = new Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 3);
static Rectangle leftArm = new Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 3);
static Rectangle rightArm = new Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 3);
static Rectangle leftLeg = new Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 3);
static Rectangle rightLeg = new Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 3);

Rectangle[] hangman = new Rectangle[5];
hangman[0] = torso;
hamgman[1] = leftArm;
//continue... 

for(int i = 0; i < mistakes; i++) g2d.draw(hangman[i]); //but then the head is left out :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of Shape: `[Shape]` say called `shapes`, or an `ArrayList<Shape>` and then fill it with `Ellipse2D`, `Rectangle2D`, `Line2D` and similar objects. Note that to draw Shape derived objects, you will need to use a Graphics2D object, and so in your JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, be sure to first cast the Graphics object to Graphics2D:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Then your for loop can loop through your array, looping from 0 to errorCount (but making sure first that errorCount is never > array's length. e.g.,

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
errorCount = Math.min(errorCount, shapes.length);
for (int i = 0; i < errorCount; i++) {
    g2.draw(shapes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I figured a list type thing would be the answer. Could you also provide the code for creating the list itself? That would help a ton.

Comment: Actually nevermind strike that, I wasn't paying attention, I could use a normal array. Thank you that worked perfectly!

Comment: @AshwinGupta: no, please don't ask for code, that's not cool here, and you really should try that yourself and then come back with questions if you're having problems with **your** code.

Comment: Okay sorry about that Hovercraft.